# How does one get $M^Ts=s$ from $M$ being stochastic and symmetric w.r.t some scalar product?

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, stochastic-matrices

Let $M \in \mathbb R_+^{N,N}$ be a nonnegative stochastic matrix and symmetric w.r.t some scalar product $\langle \cdot \, \vert \, \cdot \rangle_s$ given by some positive vector $s \in \mathbb R_*^{N}$.

On page 36 in https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-02926037/document I then read that we have

$$M^Ts=s$$
which according to the paper comes from $M \textbf{1}=\textbf{1}$ and the symmetry of $d(s)M$, where $d(s)$ is the diagonal matrix with components of $s$ on the diagonal. I have a too foggy view to actually see how we from that get $M^Ts=s.$ Can anyone help me there? And what does it exactly mean, that the matrix is symmetric w.r.t the scalar product? Havent dealt alot with matrix scalar products so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *"$M$ is symmetric with respect to the scalar product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_s$ given by a positive vector $s$"* means that $M^T\operatorname{diag}(s)=\operatorname{diag}(s)M$. So, when $M$ is row-stochastic,
$$
M^Ts
=M^T\operatorname{diag}(s)\mathbf1
=\operatorname{diag}(s)M\mathbf1
=\operatorname{diag}(s)\mathbf1
=s.
$$

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. Is there a way you can explain me one more little thing?

So on the same page, how do we get $M_1^Ts_1=s_1$ where $s_1$ are the first $k$ components of $Ps$? I cant see how the result transfers to the submatrix $M_1$..

Comment: @Tesla This is just the result of ordinary matrix-vector multiplication. Partition $s$ as $\pmatrix{s_1\\ s_2}$. Then $\pmatrix{s_1\\ s_2}=s=M^Ts=\pmatrix{M_1^T&0\\ X^T&M_2^T}\pmatrix{s_1\\ s_2}=\pmatrix{M_1^Ts_1\\ X^Ts_1+M_2^Ts_2}$. Compare. both sides and we get $s_1=M_1^Ts_1$.

Comment: Yes thanks, but dont we have $PMP^T=\begin{pmatrix} M_1 & X \\ 0 & M2 \end{pmatrix}$? As you write it, it looks you $M=\begin{pmatrix} M_1 & X \\ 0 & M2 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I mean the way you write it , it would make sense to me why we get the result, but how do we get to it when it is the matrix $PMP^T$ that you used?

Comment: @Tesla By a reindexing we may assume that $P=I$. Otherwise, partition $Ps$ as $\pmatrix{s_1\\ s_2}$. Then $\pmatrix{s_1\\ s_2}=Ps=PM^Ts=(PM^TP^T)Ps=\pmatrix{M_1^T&0\\ X^T&M_2^T}\pmatrix{s_1\\ s_2}$ and we still have $s_1=M_1^Ts_1$.